# A href in PHP Foreach $result

Tags: php, mysql, href

I have a question about PHP/MYSQL.
Here you see my php page in the browser:

[image]

And here you see my phpmyadmin database:

[image]

What I want is when I click on:"Laders" I only want to see on the next page everything in the "groep":"Laders". The problem is I don't know how to do that in a loop. Here is the code:

```
    <?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'producten'); 
$query =    "SELECT *
                    FROM producten
                    WHERE Merk = '" . 'Apple' . "' 
                    ORDER BY Artikelnummer, Artikelnaam";
                    /*echo $query;*/
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
?>
<table>
<?php
    echo '<table style="width:100%">
            <tr style="color:yellow; background-color:black;">
                <th>Apple</th>
            </tr>';
    foreach ($result AS $rij)
{

         echo '<tr style="background:blue"><td>' . $rij['Groep'] . ' </td></tr>';



}
?> </table>
```

Comment: `WHERE Merk="Apple" AND groep="Laders"`?

Answer (score -1):

```
foreach ($result AS $rij)
```

{

```
     echo '<tr style="background:blue"><td><a href="view.php?variable='.$rij['Groep'].'">'.$rij['Groep'].'</a></td></tr>';
```

}

After this, create a php file "view.php" and fetch data using $_GET['variable']